# Add and Remove action on Symfony2 controller

Tags: symfony

I'm a newbie on Symfony and I'm working at a web application which support a mobile app.
I need to build a grocery list of food products.
Products can be searched by name and if I'm interested in I can add/remove them to a shopping list with increasing unit and "+" or "-" .
I have `Product` and `ShoppingList` entities, but I have no idea how to build these functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already generated and registered your new bundle, then my best advice is to start here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html

This will help you create "CRUD" actions (Create, Read, Update, Delete). So you'll have a whole set of URLs you can hit to do things like "Create a Product" or "Delete a ShoppingList".

From there, you can launch into other actions that your application will require, like "Add a Product to the ShoppingList", or "Show the list of Products in a ShoppingList".

First, though, better make sure you're familiar with the framework. Start here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html